# Problem deploying hibernate depended project into weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, maven-3, weblogic-10.x, jboss6.x

I've been developing an application intending to deploy my war into jboss6. However, in the middle of the development, I had to deploy my application into weblogic(no experience before) 10.3.5(company policies!) Now, I am stuck. I have no success to gather the necessary libs for the weblogic. Here is the my pom fragment and the exception that I got from the web logic console.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.11</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.12</version>
</dependency>
```

exception

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.11 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
INFO  Version                         - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
INFO  Environment                     - Hibernate 3.6.7.Final
INFO  Environment                     - hibernate.properties not found
INFO  Environment                     - Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO  Environment                     - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
INFO  Version                         - Hibernate EntityManager 3.6.7.Final
INFO  Ejb3Configuration               - Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: ...]
<Sep 7, 2011 2:14:58 PM EEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1315394097821' for task '13'. Error is: 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:629)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:629)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Sep 7, 2011 2:14:58 PM EEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'beyazfatura'.>
<Sep 7, 2011 2:14:58 PM EEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:629)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:629)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Sep 7, 2011 2:15:13 PM EEST> <Error> <Console> <BEA-240003> <Console encountered the following error weblogic.application.WrappedDeploymentException: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:629)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
        at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
        at weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:39)
        at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.storeDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:349)
        at weblogic.deployment.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:124)
        at weblogic.deployment.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.<init>(ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.java:58)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.setupPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppModule.java:1790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initClassLoader(WebAppServletContext.java:3028)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:447)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:493)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:972)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:382)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:613)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:184)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ![btw, here is the web-inf/lib jars list image.](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/5104/libs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling JPA 2.0 solves the problem. Just be careful about upgrading weblogic, it changes the lib version also the names.

Comment: Yes, because Hibernate >= 3.5 supports *JPA 2.0* (so also your version 3.6.7.Final). But WebLogic 10.3.x supports out-of-the-box only JPA 1.0 - so adding to the WebLogic classpath two jars: `javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-x.jar`, `com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-x.jar` will add JPA 2.0 capabilities to the WebLogic and solve the problem.